# Calculate the bit depth from the colour count of a gif

Tags: c#, image-processing, operators

I've been reading though the gif specification trying to understand how the size of a colour table palette is calculated.

From the example on Wikipedia  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF#Example_GIF_file)

```
byte#  hexadecimal  text or
(hex)               value       Meaning
0:     47 49 46
       38 39 61     GIF89a      Header
                                Logical Screen Descriptor
6:     03 00        3            - logical screen width in pixels
8:     05 00        5            - logical screen height in pixels
A:     F7                        - GCT follows for 256 colors with
                                   resolution 3 x 8 bits/primary
```

If you look at the 10th byte you can see the Hex `F7`which represents the decimal number `247`.

Now I know from reading various code samples that this is a packed value made up from the following:

```
0x80 | // 1   : global color table flag = 1 (gct used)
0x70 | // 2-4 : color resolution
0x00 | // 5   : gct sort flag = 0
7 |; // 6-8 : gct size
0 |// background color index
0 |// pixel aspect ratio - assume 1:1
```

I've also determined that the size `7` represents the bit depth minus `1`. which can be used to determine the number of colours.

```
2 ^ (0 + 1) = 4
2 ^ (1 + 1) = 4
2 ^ (2 + 1) = 8
2 ^ (3 + 1) = 16
2 ^ (5 + 1) = 64
2 ^ (6 + 1) = 128
2 ^ (7 + 1) = 256
```

http://www.matthewflickinger.com/lab/whatsinagif/bits_and_bytes.asp
http://www.devx.com/projectcool/Article/19997/0/page/7

What I am looking to find out is how would I calculate the bit depth from the number of colours using C#.

Since this is something you would want to do quickly I would imagine using some sort of bit-shifting mechanism would be the best approach. I'm not a computer scientist though so I struggle with such things.

I've a horrible feeling it's really simple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a logarithm. Round the result up in order to calculate the bits depth needed.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns how many bits are required to store the specified
    /// number of colors. Performs a Log2() on the value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="colors"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static int GetBitsNeededForColorDepth(byte colors) {
        return (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(colors, 2));
    }
```

https://github.com/imazen/resizer/blob/c4c586b58b2211ad0f48f7d8285e951ff6f262f9/Plugins/PrettyGifs/PrettyGifs.cs#L239-L241

Comment: I should have just got you on Twitter!